# Diablo 3 Reaper of Souls Digital Deluxe Edition, Skeleton Minion?

Tags: diablo-iii

Is there any information known about what this minion is?

Will it be like a pet in most MMORPG's and just be a visual sidekick?

Or will it be like the Witch Doctor's minions, something that will do damage for me?

Note that I realize that the full knowlegde of what it will do will only be known after release, but the point is that you have to decide whether to buy the digital deluxe edition or the regular edition before you have this knowledge, so I'm guessing that others will want to know as well. Hence my question.

Comment: I'm assuming that there is some information out there since otherwise it would be akin to "We're going to sell you X but we won't tell you what X is until you've paid for it". As such, this is a pertinent question even if RoS is not out yet. You have to decide on buying the digital deluxe edition or the regular one *before* you have a chance to know what that minion will be. So I still think it is a valid question.

Comment: making the *Skeleton Minion* something like a pet or a WD's minions will make the game unbalanced where players with *Digital Deluxe* and *Collector's Edition* game will have a (huge) advantage over the normal players

Comment: The minion is going to be a non-combat based on the description.

Comment: Odd that a question that is "clearly off-topic" has gathered 2.6K views in 10 days. I'm assuming you're in touch with the userbase of this site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Skeleton Minion is the Spectral Hound Minion witch will be purely cosmetic.

[D3 Forum](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/10973297505)

[Content of the speciffic Versions](http://d3domination.com/diablo-3-news/diablo-3-reaper-souls-release-date-announced/)

Comment: OK, so the only really useful content for Diablo 3 in the digital deluxe edition will be the 3 extra character slots. Good to know. I don't have the collector's edition of D3 so I didn't know about/of the spectral hound minion. Sounds logical that it will be similar. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry i read false, but this didnt change the effect that the minion will be only cosmetic.